# for loop in matlab storing values (scalar times vector array)

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop, vector, scalar

I would like to know in matlab how to accomplish the following task:

If i have a for loop like in the following lines:

```
b=[1 2 3 4];
for i=1:1:10
x=i.*b
end
```

the code iterates i-times multiplying a scalar times the vector b; but if i put in the for loop x(i) in order to store the resulting vector of every iteration, i wouldn't get what i'm looking for. What i'm lookig for is to get:

```
x(1)=[1 2 3 4]
x(2)=[2 4 6 8]
... and so on
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in P0W's answer, you need a two-dimensional matrix to store "a vector of vectors". You can't use `x(n)`, since addresses a single value in a one-dimensional matrix.

Another solution, maybe closer to what you want, is to use cell a cell array, which allow to create a matrix containing mixed-typed values (so you can put vectors too!). They are quite similar to regular array, but you need curly brackets:

```
b=[1 2 3 4];
x = cell(1,10);   % preallocating, not necessary but always a good idea

for i = 1:10
    x{i} = i*b  % notice the curly bracket with the index
end
```

note: you don't need the `.*` operator, since is a scalar-matrix multiplication.

You can get back your values with

```
x{1} = [1 2 3 4]    % again curly brackets
x{2} = [2 4 6 8]
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Can use:

`x=[1:10]'*b`

then

`x(1,:)`

`x(2,:)`

etc